# Change the color and font of text in Shiny App

Tags: r, fonts, styles, shiny

I am using below code in `server.R` to display the text in the main panel. This is working exactly the way it should work.

```
output$text1 <- renderText({
  if(input$ag == 0) return(NULL)
  return('First 20 rows for requested AG')
})
```

Is there any way to change the font and color of the text?

Comment: AFAIK renderText just outputs its text like cat. You probably need to use CSS to change the text style. See here for a Google Groups discussion that (I think) includes your issue.

Comment: Just realised I didn't provide the url :/ [here it is](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/xWyaOryOkVs) (and on second glance it may not be in the context of `renderText`).

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use css as @jbaums indicated

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    numericInput('n', 'Number of obs', 100),
    textOutput('text1'),
    tags$head(tags$style("#text1{color: red;
                                 font-size: 20px;
                                 font-style: italic;
                                 }"
                         )
              )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$text1 <- renderText({ paste("hello input is",input$n) })
  }
))
```

Normally you would include this in a `styles.css` file but it is shown inline here to be self contained. `#text1` refers to the DOM element with `id=text1` and the contents of the curly brackets are the relevant styles.

Comment: For anyone who _does_ want to separate R and CSS, this blog includes good examples of how to do this using a separate CSS file: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html

Comment: thanks! For those who aren't familiar with the CSS syntax, can i add tags of other text outputs after `#text1` that I want to be similarily formatted? Say, separated with a comma: `#text1,#text2`?

Answer (score 64):

in `ui.r`:

```
span(textOutput("message"), style="color:red")
```

in `server.r`:

```
output$message <- renderText({"This is some red text"})
```

Comment: To add to this, you can do the same without `textOutput`, if it is to be static in the UI.

Comment: To add also the font and size: in `ui.r`: `span(textOutput("message"), style = "color:red; font-size:20px; font-family:arial; font-style:italic")`

Comment: This is an elegant, minimal solution (and improved with @EmaK's comment). Thanks to you both.

Answer (score 47):

If only want to change a certain part of the returning string, one can use `htmlOutput` instead of `textOutput`

On server side just return

```
output$text1 <- renderText({ paste("hello input is","<font color=\"#FF0000\"><b>", input$n, "</b></font>") })
```

In this way, Shiny UI will perform HTML.

Answer (score 17):

The solution by @MikeP also works with `p()`, fx `p("some text", style = "color:red")`, so you can also just wrap that in a `renderText()` from the server if you want to display it dynamically.

Comment: Too bad this isn't documented well in `?p`.