# R Shiny: Formatting text within tableOutput

Tags: r, shiny, format, output

Consider the following very simple shiny app that outputs a table of text stored in the dataframe `df`:

```
library(shiny)

df <- data.frame(id=1:3,
                   text=c('It was a good day today', 'It is good to hear from you', 'I am feeling good'),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tableOutput("freetext")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$freetext <- renderTable({ df })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

I would like the word "good" in each line to appear in red. Is this possible using `tableOutput`?

I have seen posts such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049159/change-the-color-and-font-of-text-in-shiny-app) that suggest replacing `textOutput` with `htmlOutput` in the `ui` function, but I am not sure how to extend this to a table of text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `htmlTable`, you can include some HTML in the table. For example:

```
library(shiny)
library(htmlTable)

df <- data.frame(
  id=1:3,
  text=c('It was a <span style="color:red;">good</span> day today', 
         'It is good to hear from you', 
         'I am feeling good'),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  htmlTableWidgetOutput("freetext")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$freetext <- renderHtmlTableWidget({ 
    htmlTableWidget(df) 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

[image]